# Colocar valores en una key de un JSON extraído desde otro archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, nodejs, json, api, express

Estoy haciendo una API sobre FNAF con JS, Express, Node, etc. El punto es que estoy haciendo un archivo JSON con los datos de todos los personajes, entre ellos sus apariciones en cada juego, el punto es que son muchos personajes (unos 60) y cada personaje puede tener hasta 10 apariciones, eso significaría que la key "appearances" tendría como valor un array con 10 elementos.

No sé si deba llenarlo manualmente o como se me había ocurrido, tomar los datos de mi otro archivo JSON llamado "games" donde tengo los datos de cada juego, que es lo que necesito para llenar la key de "appearances"

```
[
    {
        "name": "Freddy Fazbear", 
        "type": "Classic",
        "appearances": ["Five Nights at Freddy's 1", "Five Nights At Freddy's 2"],
        "genre": "Male"
    }
]
```

Mientras que mi JSON de "games" luce así:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Five Nights At Freddy's 1", 
        "year": "2014", 
        "engine": "ClickTeam Fusion 2.5", 
        "author": ["Scott Cawthon"]
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Five Nights At Freddy's 2", 
        "year": "2014", 
        "engine": "ClickTeam Fusion 2.5", 
        "author": ["Scott Cawthon"]
    }
]
```

Son archivos diferentes, pero, ¿Hay forma de llenar los datos de mi primer array characters.JSON con los datos de otro archivo JSON distinto?

Comment: Así como lo presentas no se puede, porque no existe ninguna relación entre el primer JSON y el 2do. Si en el 2do JSON tuvieras el nombre del protagonista se podría